# Firestore does not throw error but does not write data to the emulator

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I try to setup the emulator for end-to-end testing on my angular application.

The application works well with the remote firestore database and authentication.
The following code is executed when init the app component:

```
      const coll = collection(this.firestore ,'cities');
      const newDoc = doc(coll, 'LA');
  
      setDoc(newDoc, {
        name: 'Los angeles',
        country: 'United states'
      }).then(() => console.log('written'))
      .catch((err) => console.log('not written', err))

      const docRef = doc(this.firestore, "cities", "London");
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
```

With the remote database, these operations are well working.
The problem is that with the emulator, the writing operation logs 'written', while I cannot see any new document within the firestore database. I checked and it is not written in the remote database.
Another strange thing is that if I write a new document in the emulator UI, I cannot see it into the application. The previous code logs 'No such document!'. I have to restart the emulator (data is persisting thanks to --import and --export-on-exit options), to see the new document data in the app.

Have somebody encountered strange behaviors like this ?

Thanks for help !

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.11.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.2.0",
    "@ionic/cli": "^6.20.8",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "@osdiab/io-ts-reporters": "^1.3.2",
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^17.2.0",
    "@types/tween.js": "^17.2.0",
    "deepcopy": "^2.1.0",
    "express-ws": "^4.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.1",
    "flagpack-core": "^2.0.0",
    "fp-ts": "^2.8.2",
    "io-ts": "^2.2.10",
    "io-ts-reporters": "^1.1.0",
    "io-ts-types": "^0.5.11",
    "jsondiffpatch": "^0.4.1",
    "monocle-ts": "^2.3.3",
    "newtype-ts": "^0.3.4",
    "ng-cli": "^0.7.0",
    "numeric": "^1.2.6",
    "pako": "^2.0.2",
    "pixi.js": "^4.8.7",
    "rfdc": "^1.1.4",
    "rxjs": "*",
    "rxjs-compat": "*",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.7",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "xstate": "^4.32.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~14.1.0",
    "@cypress/schematic": "^2.5.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/pako": "^1.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "cypress": "latest",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^11.22.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^12.2.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.7",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  },
```

app.module:

```
// Angular - Firebase
import { provideAuth, connectAuthEmulator, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { enableIndexedDbPersistence, getFirestore, provideFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getApp, initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAnalytics, getAnalytics, UserTrackingService, ScreenTrackingService } from '@angular/fire/analytics';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();

      if (environment.test) {
        console.log('connect auth emulator')
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099');
      }

      return auth;
    }),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      console.log(environment)
      if (environment.test) {
        console.log('use firestore emulator')
        connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
      }

      return firestore;
    }),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),

    HttpClientModule,     
    CoreModule,
    HomePageModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,

    UserTrackingService,    // analytics listens for user changes
    ScreenTrackingService,  // analytics listens for screen changes
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```